# Call a Python function from a Jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to call a Python function inside a Jinja template?  The function will just take the string `years` and turn it into a list.

```
years = years.replace('[', '')
years = years.replace(']', '')
years = years.split(',')
```

How can I call this on `years` in the template below?

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "_macros.html" as macros %}

{% block title %}Year Results{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Year Search Results</h1>
</div>
<ul class=entries>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h3><a href="{{ url_for('main.grantinfo', applid=entry.appl_id) }}">{{ entry.appl_id }} : {{ entry.project_title }}</a></h3>
    <br>
    {% else %}
    <li><em>No entry here</em>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% if pagination %}
<div class="pagination">
    {{ macros.pagination_widget(pagination, '.yearresults', years=years) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`years` appears to be a JSON list, so use `json.loads` to parse it rather than stripping and splitting strings manually.  `years` appears to be a variable sent from the view to the template, so just do the processing in the view.

```
years = json.loads(years)
# years string "[1999, 2000, 2001]"
# becomes list [1999, 2000, 2001]
# without parsing the string manually
return render_template('years.html', years=years)
```

If you really need to make this available in templates (you probably don't), you can add `json.loads` to the Jinja globals.

```
app.add_template_global(json.loads, name='json_loads')
```

Then use it in a template like a normal function.

```
{{ macros.pagination_widget(pagination, '.yearresults', years=json_loads(years)) }}
```

Answer (score 22):

A way to call functions from within the template is using `@app.context_processor` decorator.

In python file like main.py

```
@app.context_processor
def my_utility_processor():

    def date_now(format="%d.m.%Y %H:%M:%S"):
        """ returns the formated datetime """
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format)

    def name():
        """ returns bulshit """
        return "ABC Pvt. Ltd."

    return dict(date_now=date_now, company=name)
```

In html file like footer.html

```
<p> Copyright {{ company() }} 2005 - {{ date_now("%Y") }} </p>
```

Output

```
Copyright ABC Pvt. Ltd. 2005 - 2015
```

Comment: In your example `company=name` could just be `company="ABC Pvt. Ltd."` directly, then just `{{ company }}` in `footer.html`. But you're example is great if it needs to be expanded/complexified later on, just saying it doesn't have to call a function if it's just to return some constant string (for future confused readers).

Comment: I realize that this question is tagged flask, but Google doesn't. So it should be stated that this is a Flask specific answer. Not helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible as follows:

First in your main.py file

```
def myYearLister(year):
    return year.INTOLISTORWHATEVER
```

then include the following somewhere in main.py( better do it after the function) in order to make the function globally accessible

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(myYearLister=myYearLister)
```

Lastly, you can call or use the function from your template as such

```
<div> {{ myYearLister(anything) }} </div>
```